# Creating table space steps

Tags: oracle, tablespaces

In order for me to create space in the database is this all I need to do?

```
alter tablespace USER_DATA_TBS add datafile '/oradata/bosv/user_data04.dbf' size 10m;
```

Or are there other steps I need to take?
I looked at [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tspaces002.htm#ADMIN11366).

I would appreciate if you could point me in the correct direction.

This is what I have after I created  a datafile:
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems like duplicate questions are being posted. Please consider revising your questions so that they differ substantially from each other. [Question 1: creating tablespacesteps](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/282503/15356) and [question 2: Increasing the size of the Oracle datafile](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/282499/15356)

Answer (score 0):

What you did, was to add another datafile (quite *tiny* one, though) to an existing tablespace. If that was your intention, then I'd say you succeeded.

However, as title says "CREATE" and if you wanted to create another tablespace, then you should have used `CREATE TABLESPACE` command (which is also described in document whose link you posted).